# androidx.media2.player.MediaPlayer combining two sounds

Tags: android

I have two instances of androidx.media2.player.MediaPlayer, one for playing .mp4, one for playing .wav. I want them both to play audio simultaneously.

I am using `setAudioAttributes` for two players, but as soon as I set the attributes for both player, none of them plays sound, and the video player doesn't even play video.

```
val soundFile = course.header.directory + soundFileName
val file = File(soundFile)
val fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(
    file,
    ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
val mediaItem = FileMediaItem.Builder(fileDescriptor).build()
audioPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
audioPlayer.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributesCompat.Builder()
    .setContentType(AudioAttributesCompat.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
    .setUsage(AudioAttributesCompat.USAGE_MEDIA)
    .build()
)
audioPlayer.prepare().addListener({
    videoPlayer.play()
    audioPlayer.play()
}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
```

I set attributes to `videoPlayer` in a similar way.

I've been trying to set the same session id to both players, but it didn't help.

Blocking the thread for five seconds appears to work around the problem, but I don't know why:

```
audioPlayer.prepare().addListener({
    videoPlayer.play()
    audioPlayer.play()
    Thread.sleep(5000)
}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution. I've moved on to `ExoPlayer`, which doesn't have `setAudioAttributes`.